# TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

Tags: mocha.js, babeljs

What does the following error mean, and how should I fix it?

```
$ npm test

> location-autosuggest@3.0.0 test /Users/mishamoroshko/location-autosuggest
> mocha test --compilers js:babel/register



  compareKeys()
    should return -1
      1) when first key is different


  0 passing (301ms)
  1 failing

  1) compareKeys() should return -1 when first key is different:
     TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
      at Context.<anonymous> (compare-keys/compare-keys.test.js:3:16)
```

Here are the relevant parts:

**compare-keys/compare-keys.test.js**

```
1. 'use strict';
2. 
3. import { expect } from 'chai';
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "mocha test --compilers js:babel/register"
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "stage": 0
}
```

**mocha.opts**

I don't have one.

**Versions**

- babel: 5.5.1
- mocha: 2.2.5
- chai: 3.0.0

Comment: Similar question stackoverflow.com/a/29130322/1909531 Here I found the solution exclude: /node_modules/

Comment: My answer for same question https://stackoverflow.com/a/44666529/1114926

Answer (score 1):

Since ES5, in strict mode, you cannot use some properties of arguments like  `callee`, etc. 
See for example the disclaimer on MDN on the [callee page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) :

> The 5th edition of ECMAScript (ES5) forbids use of arguments.callee()
>   in strict mode. Avoid using arguments.callee() by either giving
>   function expressions a name or use a function declaration where a
>   function must call itself.

`chai` may use one of these properties.

Comment: Isn't babel ignores `node_modules` by default? See: http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/#usage

Comment: I guess it's not babel but the bundle itself that contains a top level 'use strict' and the library that use the denied property

Answer (score -2):

I updated babel to 5.5.3 and it fixed the issue.

Comment: I have this same problem but that didnt seem to fix it for me. I have babel@5.5.3 mocha@2.2.5 any ideas?