# Failing to run tests using Karma

Tags: javascript, webpack, karma-runner, karma-mocha, karma-webpack

I am setting up Karma to simplify unit tests in a legacy project. The problem is, I am getting an error `You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!`. As I have found, this is a very non-specific error, so I am at a loss of how to debug it further. I have reduced my setup to the bare minimum, but the error still persists.

Here is the karma config file:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: [ 'PhantomJS' ], //run in Phantom
    autoWatch: false,
    singleRun: true, //just run once by default
    frameworks: [ 'mocha', 'chai', 'sinon', 'chai-sinon' ], // test frameworks
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    files: [
      './js/test/tests.webpack.js' //just load this file
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './js/test/tests.webpack.js': [ 'webpack', 'sourcemap' ] //preprocess with webpack and our sourcemap loader
    },
    reporters: [ 'mocha' ], //report results in this format
    webpack: { // webpack settings
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
        ]
      }
    },
    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true
    },
    plugins: [
        'karma-mocha',
        'karma-webpack',
        'karma-sourcemap-loader',
        'karma-mocha-reporter',
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
        'karma-chai',
        'karma-sinon',
        'karma-chai-sinon'
    ]
  });
};
```

Here are the packages I have installed (from package.json):

```
"babel-core": "^6.9.1",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
"babel-plugin-module-alias": "^1.5.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
"chai": "^3.5.0",
"karma": "^1.0.0",
"karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
"karma-chai-sinon": "^0.1.5",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
"karma-mocha": "^1.0.1",
"karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.4",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.1",
"karma-sinon": "^1.0.5",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
"mocha": "^2.5.3",
"phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
"phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.2",
"sinon": "^1.17.4",
"sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
"webpack": "^1.13.1"
```

Here is .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

And here is the test file that I am referencing in karma.conf.js (tests.webpack.js). My initial idea was to require all spec files in it, but now I have changed it to run at least a single test. Still no luck:

```
import chai from 'chai';
var expect = chai.expect;

console.log('I was found');
it('works', function () {
    expect(true).to.equal(true);
})
```

Could you please advise how to debug this problem further?

**UPDATE:** Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/azangru/9dfde16eb351090c40c33d8214e51985) with a minimal reproducible case. I must be doing something wrong there, because I am still receiving the error `You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!`, but I can't figure out what my mistake is.

Comment: How exactly are you running this? Please include the commands you are using for webpack and which directory you are running from.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg: I have created a gist with a minimal reproducible case, a link to which can be found in the UPDATE section of my question. The tests are run by issuing `npm run test-karma` command. In the minimal reproducible case, the test file is in the same directory as the karma config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the reference to `chai-sinon` in karma config. When I get rid of it, the test runs. I can't exactly explain why, but perhaps there is version incompatibility going on.

Comment: Wow! Just wow!

Only I am getting a different error now in my minimal case — `Type error [native code] Assertion@webpack:///~/chai/lib/chai/assertion.js:33:42 <- tests.webpack.js:4242:43 expect@webpack:///~/chai/lib/chai/interface/expect.js:9:30 <- tests.webpack.js:5963:31
webpack:///tests.webpack.js:9:11 <- tests.webpack.js:62:12` Is this the same as you are getting?

Comment: Nope. That's not the error I'm getting. I get the same error as you originally posted. When I remove `chai-sinon`, the test runs as expected.

Comment: It looks like your problem is happening because chai cannot be resolved

Comment: I am getting these weird error messages (tried both Phantom and Chrome launchers). This is the error when running the test with Phantom: http://i.imgur.com/58iVulh.png , and this is the error when running the test with Chrome: http://i.imgur.com/eCcdyNF.png

Comment: Oh, I think I am transpiling node_modules with babel, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105947/babel-karma-chai-gives-typeerror-caller-callee-and-arguments-proper . Silly me.

Comment: Yay, added the `exclude: /node_modules/` statement. Now the test runs. Weee!